# RequestLocationUpdates throws Java.Lang.Exception

Tags: java, android, xamarin, locationmanager

Method OnResume (**_locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates**) raises **"Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Exception'"** on Samsung Note 1 (works on SGS4).

Permissions: android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION added.

Sources can be found on github: https://github.com/constructor-igor/sms2

```
[Activity (Label = "sms2", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity, ILocationListener
{
...
    private LocationManager _locationManager;
...
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
       ...
      _locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
    }
    protected override void OnResume()
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Debug ("OnResume", "");
                base.OnResume ();

                m_smsSentBroadcastReceiver = new SMSSentReceiver();
                m_smsDeliveredBroadcastReceiver = new SMSDeliveredReceiver();

                RegisterReceiver(m_smsSentBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));
                RegisterReceiver(m_smsDeliveredBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_DELIVERED"));

                _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(_locationProvider, 0, 0, this);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, String.Format("OnResume failed, becasue '{0}'", e.Message), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
```

added screen with full stack:
http://cdn.vanillaforums.com/xamarin.vanillaforums.com/FileUpload/53/476688d11ac140e7c6aca6650348ce.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provider you are trying to use doesn't exist on that device.
You can check out the reason for `IllegalArgumentException` in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: seems _locationProvider = String.Empty and RequestLocationUpdates fails. Now I try to tests the version on Galaxy Note I. thank you.